# Name of the theorem "any totally bounded and closed subset in a complete metric space, is compact"

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, terminology, compactness, complete-spaces

I know this theorem and its proof, my question is that, what is the name of this theorem? Some guys refers it as "Hausdorff theorem", but I am not sure.

Comment: It's just a direct corollary of the general result: $(X,d)$ is compact iff it is totally bounded and complete, and this theorem does not have a name of a person commonly associated with it AFAIK.

Comment: That general result is 4.3.29 in Engelking and his historical notes say that Fréchet proved it first in 1910 (but in other termininology, he did not use totally bounded as a concept).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this has any simple name; Paul Sally's book calls it the Heine-Borel Theorem, but most sources name Heine-Borel a much more specific specialization of this broad result.

Comment: what is the title of Paul Sally's book?

Comment: Yeah,  I usually hear Heine-Borel refer to the specific case for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Heine-Borel is theorem on $\mathbb R^n$, in metric space, the "totally bounded" must be replaced, so I don't think it should be as Heine-Borel theorem

Comment: @JieFan Fundamentals of Mathematical Analysis by Paul J. Sally Jr.